# Name of non-complete graph with certain properties

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for a graph with the following criteria?

- not a complete graph
- has at least `n` vertices (let's say `n > 3` to exclude trivial cases)
- where every vertex's degree is at least `n`.

Or, is there a class of graphs that tend to have this kind of pattern?
I've run into graphs like this in my research, and I'm hoping to tap into a body of existing knowledge on them.

For example:
[image: picture of graph]

Comment: Sorry, I meant n > 4. Yes, these are simple undirected graphs. Only one edge between each pair of vertices.

Comment: Ack, I wasn't thinking when responding to your question. I updated it to say n > 3. Trivial cases involve degree of 3 or less. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I don't see what's so trivial about graphs of degree 3.

Answer (score 2):

The second condition is redundant given the third: if every vertex has degree $n$, there must be at least $n+1$ vertices.

I would call graphs with the third condition "graphs with minimum degree at least $n$" or "graphs $G$ with $\delta(G) \ge n$". This is concise enough that no further terminology has developed.

There isn't a nice way to exclude the complete graph. You could say "other than complete graphs", but first double-check that whatever you're saying isn't *also* true for complete graphs, just in case. I guess you could also say "graphs $G$ with $n \le \delta(G) \le |V(G)|-2$", since complete graphs are distinguished by having $\delta(G)=|V(G)|-1$.

If you're looking for properties of such graphs, you should look for properties of graphs with minimum degree at least $n$; excluding complete graphs probably won't get you any more properties beyond that.